# Angular Style Injection into <head></head>

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I use angular material and need to overwrite some styles. Right now I encountered a problem where  my custom style doesn't get applied to the material component. There is no nice way to make the selector more specific and I don't want to use `!important`.

Therefore I'd like to know: is there a way to determine the 'injection order' of styles in the `index.html`?
Like: achieve, that `<link rel="stylesheet" href="...">` gets injected after all the `<style>...</style>`. I looked for something in the documentation for the `angular.json` but couldn't find anything.

[image]

Comment: Indeed, this is not the good approach. Why do you think you cannot set a more specific selector ? Can you show the selector ? If you want to override a material selector, it should be easy.

Comment: This is a great use case for !important. I use it for many of my Material style overrides.